# How to covert local time to EST react native android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I need to convert local system time to EST time in react native

```
new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: 'America/New_York' })).getTime();
```

I have tried as above but it only works for IOS not for android

Comment: I would suggest using moment.js

Comment: @AshanJayasundara I'v checked it on android (emulator) - it seems working correctly, what is your expectations?

Comment: @TKoL yes it is working on simulator but it does not work in actual device